# Excel - simple number formatting

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a field with some numerical values. The formatting in these fields works great if you are using the buttons at the top (left, center, right align). However, once you format the numbers with commas Excel right-aligns the field and the other formatting buttons do not change it.

What am I doing wrong? This seems so simple.

What I need is something like this:

```
|    $ 1,000,000    |
|    $ 5,000        |
```

And what I am getting is like:

```
|$         1,000,000|
|$             5,000|
```

Regardless of how the formatting buttons are selected.

Or, this is even fine:

```
|$      1,000,000   |
|$      5,000       |
```

I just need the numbers to align with their left-most digit.

---

EDIT:

With the approch of formatting via the menus, this is the result.

```
|      $1,000,000   |
|       $5,000      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button on the toolbar applies the Accounting format. Select the cells you want to format, and from the formatting dropdown or the Format Cells dialog box choose the Currency format instead. By default it will give you decimal places, but these can be removed.

[image: Currency Format]

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. I tried this already and the result was close. I edited the OP to depict the resulting format changes. I am trying to get a space between the '$' character and the aligned left-most digit. ---`$ 1,000,000`

Comment: To get the space, use this custom format: $ #,##0.

Comment: I tried that before also. Although, this is the strategy that worked. What I did was added the custom formatting `$ #,#` with spaces before the '$' character and then left-justified the cells.

Answer (score 0):

For a format as below (covering negatives and zero) try:

> $ #,##0;-$ #,##0; $ -

[image: SO17998018 example]

(left aligned).